# timer triggered mysql with while statement - not fetching all data

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have developed a winform which requires constant contact with a mysql database to make sure all "calls" are fetched and up to date - the problem I have run into is that my listview is only being populated with 1 line per timer click. this timer should activate a while statement that should process all data and in fact should also be clearing the listview to receive updated data. why is my listview only populating 1 item per tick?

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ListView2.Items.Clear()
    con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;" _
& "user id=username;" _
& "password=password;" _
& "database=DMT"
        adptr = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * , s.fid AS sfid, s.name AS sname, s.faddress AS sfaddress, s.fcity AS sfcity, s.fstate AS sfstate, s.fcontnumb AS sfcontnumb, s.fcontname AS sfcontname, s.fcontract AS sfcontract, d.fid AS dfid, d.name AS dname, d.faddress AS dfaddress, d.fcity AS dfcity, d.fstate AS dfstate, d.fcontnumb AS dfcontnumb, d.fcontname AS dfcontname, d.fcontract AS dfcontract FROM calls c LEFT JOIN facilities s ON c.Scene = s.fid LEFT JOIN facilities d ON c.Dest = d.fid WHERE putime < now( ) + INTERVAL 12 HOUR && Rdisp IS NULL ORDER BY putime desc", con)
    Try
        adptr.Fill(pendrun)
    Catch err As Exception
        Dim strError As String = "Exception: & err.ToString()"
    End Try
    If pendrun.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        While pop < pendrun.Rows.Count - 1
            TempStr(0) = pendrun.Rows(pop)("RID")
            Select Case pendrun.Rows(pop)("Utype")
                Case 1
                    TempStr(1) = "BLS Ambulance"
                Case 2
                    TempStr(1) = "ALS Ambulance"
                Case 3
                    TempStr(1) = "SCT Ambulance"
                Case 4
                    TempStr(1) = "Wheelchair Van"
                Case 5
                    TempStr(1) = "Taxi"
            End Select

            Select Case pendrun.Rows(pop)("Curgency")
                Case 1
                    TempStr(2) = "Scheduled"
                Case 2
                    TempStr(2) = "Non-Scheduled"
                Case 3
                    TempStr(2) = "ASAP"
                Case 4
                    TempStr(2) = "STAT"
            End Select
            TempStr(3) = pendrun.Rows(pop)("Pname")
            TempStr(4) = pendrun.Rows(pop)("Texttime")
            TempStr(5) = pendrun.Rows(pop)("sname") & " - " & pendrun.Rows(pop)("sfaddress") & ", " & pendrun.Rows(pop)("sfcity") & ", " & pendrun.Rows(pop)("sfstate")
            TempStr(6) = pendrun.Rows(pop)("dname") & " - " & pendrun.Rows(pop)("dfaddress") & ", " & pendrun.Rows(pop)("dfcity") & ", " & pendrun.Rows(pop)("dfstate")
            TempNode = New ListViewItem(TempStr)
            ListView2.Items.Add(TempNode)
            pop += 1
        End While
    End If

End Sub
```

I have verified it is in fact linked to the timer directly (1 item per tick) by varying the timer from 1 second to 30 seconds and it does directly change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code never resets "pop"'s value. That's what's causing trouble, I'm pretty sure. It keeps incrementing 1 value every tick, never able to do all of them because pop is set to one less than the while's max.